# Different Upper and Lower Bound

Tags: asymptotics

Is there a function or algorithms whose upper bound and lower bound are different?

For example f(X) i.e f(X) = O(X^2) and f(X) = Omega(X)

Comment: $f(X) = X$ satisfies $f(X) = O(X^2)$ and $f(X) = \Omega(X)$ as $x \to \infty$.  Is this the kind of example you're looking for?

Comment: Yes but in this case f(X) = O(X) and f(X) = Omega(X) also so the exampe doesn't satisfy my condition